# Video Recording of Webdriver session with TestContainers

Tags: selenium, kotlin, selenium-webdriver, testcontainers

I am looking for the good example about how to record a webdriver session inside docker via testcontainers. Here is my solution:

```
lateinit var docker: BrowserWebDriverContainer<Nothing>

fun main() {
    //1. Create webdriver and start Docker
    val webDriver = startDocker()

    //2. Open some page
    webDriver.get("https://www.github.com")

    //3. Stop the webdriver
    webDriver.quit()

    //4. Notify docker to save video
    docker.afterTest(TestDi(), Optional.of(Throwable("")))

    //5. Stop docker container
    docker.stop()
}

fun create(): WebDriver {
    WebDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.CHROME).driverVersion("latest").setup()
    return ChromeDriver(getCapabilities())
}

private class RecordingFileFactoryImpl: RecordingFileFactory {
    override fun recordingFileForTest(vncRecordingDirectory: File?, prefix: String?, succeeded: Boolean) =
        Paths.get("video.mp4").toFile()
}

private class TestDi: TestDescription {
    override fun getTestId() = ""
    override fun getFilesystemFriendlyName() = "/build/"
}

private fun startDocker() : WebDriver {
    docker = BrowserWebDriverContainer<Nothing>()
        .withCapabilities(getCapabilities())
    docker.withRecordingMode(
        BrowserWebDriverContainer.VncRecordingMode.RECORD_ALL,
        File("build"),
        VncRecordingContainer.VncRecordingFormat.MP4
    )
    docker.withRecordingFileFactory(
        RecordingFileFactoryImpl()
    )
    docker.start()

    return docker.webDriver
}

private fun getCapabilities(): DesiredCapabilities {
    val caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()

    val options = ChromeOptions()
    options.addArguments(
        "--allow-insecure-localhost",
        "--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist",
        "--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection",
    )

    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)
    caps.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true)

    val chromePrefs = HashMap<String, Any>()
    chromePrefs["profile.default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
    chromePrefs["download.default_directory"] = "build"
    chromePrefs["safebrowsing.enabled"] = "true"

    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs)

    return caps
}
```

https://github.com/nachg/DockerDemo

And it works. If you run it you will get an `video.mp4` inside project dir. But I am expecting that the video will be completed after the step #3. Actually the video is completing after step #4, and it contains some seconds of the blank screen. I don't want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by myself. Soltion was - to copy the video stream file and convert the copy. Please see the details in my last commit: https://github.com/nachg/DockerDemo/commit/9664eb818fc95979c681b6ce806b92e7e647d413